# Stop PyQGIS script but not close QGIS program

Tags: python, pyqgis

How do I stop a PyQGIS script from running (preventing the execution of the rest of the script) without closing QGIS?

While running a script from the python console window, the follow command will close QGIS entirely, as opposed to just stopping the script.

```
sys.exit()
```

Is there a way to simply and easily stop a python script without purposely raising an ugly looking traceback?

Comment: At the moment I call dud variables like purposelyEndingScript , so that the traceback stops the script where I want it to stop. It would be great if there was a way that is nicer and isn't big and clumsy...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a GIS question but a general question of program logic and control flow.

Does your code run for a long time and you want to cancel it (I don't know if that is possible) or do you repeatedly need your code to run up to a certain point? If that's the case, then use a function and a control variable to check at various points in the code flow:

```
def myFunction(run_up_to_step=999):
  current_step = 1
  #step1
  ### code for step 1 here ###
  current_step += 1
  if current_step > run_up_to_step:
    return
  #step2
  ### code for step 2 here ###
  current_step += 1
  if current_step > run_up_to_step:
    return
  #step3
  ### code for step 3 here ###
  ...

# and then call the function with the last step that should run as a parameter
myFunction(2)
```

This is one way to achieve this. Even better would be to structure your steps in separate functions each, and then call those functions. That way you can reuse the functions elsewhere.

Comment: Is there really no way to do this without a function for testing puposes?

Comment: It would be so much quicker than commenting out with ''', because you always have to add and remove it two times...

Comment: I have solved it by importing iface and inserting iface.addVectorLayer(some_letter)